# ng2-pdf-viewer with Angular 6 'pdf-viewer' is not known object

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular6

I'm trying ti integrate `ng2-pdf-viewer` in my angular 6 application with webpack.

I have followed the instructions for adding the module here;

[ng2-pdf-viewer instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)

So, the entry is added to my package .json, which is as follows;

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --env=dev --open --hot --inline --port 8080\" \"dotnet run\" ",
    "node-sass": "npm rebuild node-sass",
    "webpack-dev": "webpack --env=dev",
    "webpack-production": "webpack --env=prod",
    "build-dev": "npm run webpack-dev",
    "build-production": "npm run webpack-production",
    "watch-webpack-dev": "webpack --env=dev --watch --color",
    "watch-webpack-production": "npm run build-production --watch --color",
    "publish-for-iis": "npm run build-production && dotnet publish -c Release",
    "test": "karma start",
    "test-ci": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "tslint ./ClientApp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^6.0.7",
    "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^6.2.0",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "mousetrap": "1.6.2",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.0",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "AfterBuild": [
      "node-sass",
      "build-dev"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can confirm that the ng2-pdf-viewer folder has been added to my node_modules folder.

I have then added to my `app.module.ts`;

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutes } from "./app.routes";
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module";
import { HomeModule } from "./home/home.module";
import { PressModule } from "./press/press.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        PdfViewerModule,
        AppRoutes,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
        HomeModule,
        PressModule
    ],

    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Then in the my `press.component.html` i have the following;

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "press-component",
    templateUrl: "./press.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./press.component.scss"]
})

export class PressComponent {
    pdfSrc: string = "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf";

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

and my `press.component.html`;

```
            <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
                    [render-text]="true"
                    style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

However, when I run `npm run webpack-production` i get the following error;

```
ERROR in : Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'.
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'src' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("sm-12 text-center">
            <pdf-viewer [ERROR ->][src]="pdfSrc"
                        [render-text]="true"
                        style="display:") : Can't bind to 'render-text' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'.
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'render-text' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
                        [ERROR ->][render-text]="true"
                        style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
        </div> ") : 'pdf-viewer' is not a known element:
1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            [ERROR ->]<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
                        [render-text]="true"
                        sty")
```

Can anyone help to explain why this is occurring and how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you solved it? Because I too facing the same and couldn't able to rectify it.

Answer (score 5):

This error is due to Angular is not able to find PdfViewerModule. Looks like you are having a sub module and PdfViewerModule declaration is missing there.
Do you have a sub module called something like 'press.module.js'?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone falling on this situation, the problem is the PdfViewer example use the AppComponent to show the pdfViewer demo, but must of us will insert the pdf-viewer tag inside a page module.

So, instead of importing PdfViewerModule on the app.module.ts file, you just have to do it in your page's module file (your-page.module.ts).

Answer (score 1):

I had error like so many people. After many attempts i also added in array providers:[PdfViewerComponent] this is my solution with angular 9 in details:

in `app.module.ts`  added

`import { PdfViewerModule, PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';`

`imports:[PdfViewerModule]`

`providers:[PdfViewerComponent ]`

But if you want instead  providers:[PdfViewerComponent ] in app.module.ts  put this directly in YourComponent  inside `@Component({ selector:'bla', templateUrl:'bla', styleUrls:['bla'] , providers: [PdfViewerComponent ] })`

Comment: Thanks, this is what fixed it for me.